# How to make caret bigger in React, bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Is it possible to make the Caret a bit bigger using React Bootstrap?

```
<DropdownButton
    pullRight
    id="drpSetting"
    title={menuTitle}
>
    <MenuItem>Inställningar</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>Betalningsinställningar</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={::this.logout}>Logga ut</MenuItem>
</DropdownButton>
```

Comment: Increase the font size.

Comment: Have already tried, its not woking, it works just for the title but not for the caret.

Comment: What caret are you talking about?

Comment: Dropdown menu Caret

Comment: In order to do that you would also be increasing the size of the dropdown.

Comment: I just want to increase size of Caret, is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: But how, this is my question? :D

Comment: I don't know React Bootstrap, but you can change the bootstrap 3 .caret size with CSS: "border-width". Maybe you can implement this in React? border-width:10px;

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add to answers given above, that you should add 
`border-bottom-width: 0;`.

```
.caret {
  border-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-width: 0; //<---- Here
}
```

[Updated grusl83's JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8w8c8sk6/1/)

Also you can give custom className to your dropdown

```
<DropdownButton
    pullRight
    id="drpSetting"
    title={menuTitle}
    className="custom-dropdown-btn">
>
```

And then use it to style your caret:

```
.custom-dropdown-btn .caret {
  border-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can share screenshot of your inspected caret styles, so we can figure out the problem?

Comment: When I change .caret class in Google Chrome Developer tools then it works, but when I use the same CSS in my CSS file then it doesn't work :O

.caret {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top: 8px dashed;
    border-top: 4px solid dashed;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your existing CSS file

```
.caret {
  border-width: 10px;
}
```

Doing that ensures all rendered dropdowns that contain a `span` with a class of `caret` increase in size.

Comment: Its a React bootstrap. This code gives border to my Title. I want just Caret to become bigger. Please check my code, I have a DropdownButton which has a caret by default.

Comment: I saw that, when that code is transpiled, it returns html. You can inspect it in the browser if you want to be sure.
When you do, you'd see a `span` element with class of `caret`, that's what creates the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

CSS approach:

```
.caret {
  border-width:10px;
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38821/